# Recursive function to create tree

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to create a function that creates a tree with recursion but I keep getting a segmentation fault each time I try. I have created the following function. Can you help me understand what is going wrong and how I can fix it? The data is stored from 1 and up in a data[i] array.

```
void create_tree(nary_node* root, data *data)
{
  if(root == NULL) return;

  int i;
  static int datacount; 

  for(i=0; i<root->data.n; i++) { // For each child in the root
    append_child(root, data[datacount]);
    create_tree(root->child[i], data);
  }
}
```

It depends on a helper function append_child():

```
void append_child(nary_node *root, data data)
{
  int i = 0;
  while (root->child[i] != NULL) i++;

  root->child[i] = create_node(data.n, data);
}
```

The manual tree construction would be as follows:

```
append_child(root, data[1]);
append_child(root, data[2]);
append_child(root->child[0], data[3]);
append_child(root->child[0], data[4]);
append_child(root->child[1], data[5]);
append_child(root->child[1], data[6]);
```

This would create a tree with two nodes from root with two children each.
It works fine manually, but I am having trouble with the recursive part.

Just added structs for and explainations for context if needed:

```
/*
  Data contains all possible data for each node 
*/
typedef struct 
{
  int n;  // Number of children
} data;

/* 
  nary_node contains each nodes data and an array of pointers
  to it's children. An arbitrary max-value was set to 10-children.
*/
typedef struct s_nary_node 
{
  data data;
  struct s_nary_node* child[10];
} nary_node;
```

in main():

```
int main(void) {
   data data[99];
   nary_node *root = create_node(data[0].n, data[0]);
   create_tree(root, data);
}
```

in create_node():

```
nary_node *create_node(int children, data data)
{
  int i = 0;
  nary_node *node = (nary_node*)malloc(sizeof(nary_node));

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    node->child[i] = NULL;

  node->data = data;
  node->data.n = children;
  return node;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In particular, the `main` that initialises `root` and calls `create_tree`.

Comment: `root->data.n` is not assigned in posted code, yet used in `for(i=0; i<root->data.n; i++)`

Comment: Im sorry for the late edit. Just added the main() and create_node() function that main depends on to create the root node. It should compile exacly as on my machine if you copy the code now. @kaylum

Comment: @chux Im sorry. Have added context so you can see the assignment. It is in create_node() that is called in main and indirectly in append_children() because it calls create_node().

Comment: What does your `data` contain? It is not initialised in the posted code.

Comment: In `main()`, `data data[99]; nary_node *root = create_node(data[0].n, data[0]);` --> Code is giving un-initialized, un-assigned `data[0].n` to `create_node()`.  so from the very begin code is messed up.  Rest of code is moot.

Comment: @n.m. It contains the number of children for each node. It is read in from an XML file. Data[0]: 2 Data[1]: 6 Data[2]: 6 Data[3]: 2 Data[4]: 2 - Data[14]: 2 and Data[0] to

Comment: There is no way to reproduce your results without having your data.

Comment: the main and create_node are unnecessary and actually make it harder to understand as they are written now, check my answer

Comment: @n.m. I uploaded the XML file and the function to read it here. Thought it could be reproduced without. https://kobra.io/#/e/-KZDtE5I0mRYwc4YvLUx

Comment: @Krzak Have added datacount++ in the end of create_tree() :-). The segmentation faut is still happening though.

Comment: @JohnLag check it again now :)

Comment: @Krzak With your proposed solution the first two nodes are being appended to the root, however when trying to print the values of their children im getting a segmentation fault. For some reason it is not building the tree the same way as the manual tree creation.

Comment: @JohnLag how are you printing the values?

Comment: printf("Level 1: n: %d \n", root->child[0]->data.n);
printf("Level 1: n: %d \n", root->child[1]->data.n);
printf("Level 2: D1 n: %d \n", root->child[0]->child[0]->data.n); // error when created recursively
printf("Level 2: D1 n: %d \n", root->child[0]->child[1]->data.n); // error

Comment: @Krzak The only difference is in the functions. It prints the values just fine with the manual tree construction.

Comment: Now I do agree with @kaylum there's too much code to analyze now, can you make a unit test with data initialized by hand?
Besides now I noticed, that the first call should have `datacount` 1 instead of 0

Comment: @JohnLag I've tested my code with `data data[99];
 data[0].n = 2;
 data[1].n = 2;
 data[2].n = 2;
 data[3].n = 0;
 data[4].n = 0;
 data[5].n = 0;
 data[6].n = 0;` and it seems to work fine. Check your data reading code.

Comment: @Krzak Will try to make a unit test with hard coded data and see if it yields the expected results. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JohnLag No problem and good luck with your task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the recursion calls you will notice that it expands as follows:

```
append_child(root, data[0]);
append_child(root->child[0], data[0]);
append_child(root->child[0]->child[0], data[0]);
append_child(root->child[0]->child[0]->child[0], data[0]);
[...]
append_child(root->child[0]->[...]->child[0]->child[0], data[0]);
```

As you never increase the `datacount` and apparently in your example `data[0].n == 2`
Although a simple postincrementation won't give you the expected result, because it will expand instead into:

```
append_child(root, data[1]);
append_child(root->child[0], data[2]);
append_child(root->child[0]->child[0], data[3]);
append_child(root->child[0]->child[0]->child[0], data[4]);
[...]
append_child(root->child[0]->[...]->child[0]->child[0], data[?]);
```

Instead try this:

```
void create_tree(nary_node* root, data *data)
{
    if(root == NULL) return;

    int i;
    static int datacount = 1; 

    for(i=0; i<root->data.n; i++) { // For each child in the root
        append_child(root, data[datacount++]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<root->data.n; i++) {
        create_tree(root->child[i], data);
    }
}
```

Not as elegant, but should provide you with the same result as your expected manual 'creation'.